# How to change text color in a certain listView position?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have ListView. When I scrolling list , the cell of the list  in a certain position changes color. How to make the color of the text in this cell changes too?

My code part for changing cell color:

```
@Override
        public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            for (int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View childView = view.getChildAt(i);
                if (i == 1) {
                    childView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_color);
                } else {
                    childView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no_select_color);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for your `TextView` in `childView`, cast it to `TextView` and then use `setTextColor` method

some example onliner:

`((TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id)).setTextColor(i==1 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);`

or if your `childView` IS a `TextView` then you may use:

`((TextView) childView).setTextColor(i==1 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);`

Comment: thank you. I followed your advice and  did this: View childView = view.getChildAt(i);
               ` if (i == 1) {
                    childView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_color); ((TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.textRow)).setTextColor( Color.RED);                              
                } else {
                    childView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no_select_color);((TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.textRow)).setTextColor( Color.RED);
                }`                             and it works.